# Running an .exe installer (on windows) through command line - and having it press "next" automatically

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, exe

I'd like to run an .exe command for an installer of some software, and have "something" which presses the "next" button every-time the installer asks for it.

Is it possible to command that through a command when running the .exe?

If not, what is the simplest (programming) tool that might accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look into `AutoIT`

Comment: Most installers have command line switches.

Comment: Blender - how can such be discovered?

Comment: @TalGalili: Open command prompt and run `path\to\installer.exe /?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/). It's a very simple set of tools designed for tasks such as yours.